# Cron expression every 15th of the month or the next weekday if during weekend

Tags: cron, expression

I m trying to get a cron expression that run every 15th of the month or the next weekday if the 15th is on a weekend.

the expression: 0 10 15W * ? is almost doing the job but it doesn t work if the 15th is a saturday (if will run the friday before).
Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: See this link if it helps: https://linuxhint.com/cron-job-that-runs-weekdays-only/

Comment: Always lunch your script on the 15th.  The first thing your script does is check if it is a Saturday.  No, keep going.  Yes, call the `at` command to setup a new execution the next day.